# Laravel query/access DB information

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```php
public function countPeople($id = 0, $country = false)
{
    if ($id == 0) {
        $s = Group::leftJoin('user_hobbies', 'user_hobbies.hobby_id', '=', 'groups.hobby_id')
            ->where('groups.hobby_id', $this->hobby_id)
            ->select(DB::raw('count(user_hobbies.user_id) as count'))
            ->get()
            ->first();
    } else if ($country) {
        $s = Group::leftJoin('user_hobbies', 'user_hobbies.hobby_id', '=', 'groups.hobby_id')
            ->leftJoin('user_locations', 'user_locations.user_id', '=', 'user_hobbies.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'user_locations.city_id')
            ->where('groups.hobby_id', $this->hobby_id)
            ->where('cities.country_id', $country)
            ->select(DB::raw('count(user_hobbies.user_id) as count'))
            ->get()
            ->first();
    } else {
        $s = Group::leftJoin('user_hobbies', 'user_hobbies.hobby_id', '=', 'groups.hobby_id')
            ->leftJoin('user_locations', 'user_locations.user_id', '=', 'user_hobbies.user_id')
            ->where('groups.hobby_id', $this->hobby_id)->where('user_locations.city_id', $id)
            ->select(DB::raw('count(user_hobbies.user_id) as count'))
            ->get()
            ->first();
    }

    if ($s) {
        return $s->count;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Beginner here.. I'm using another persons code to try to learn/understand a few problems. There exists this function in the controller that counts members in a group, but it doesn't give access to that persons other information, like name, photo.. etc.. Is it possible from this function to use the same function and return it as a view? Would that give me the access to the user information?

I'm not yet so well informed on how to query the DB so fluently.
Any help useful! thank you.

Comment: Sidenote, `->get()->first()` is completely redundant, just call `->first()`, since it calls `->get()` internally . As for returning this as a view, as long as this is in a Controller function, you can do `return view('example')->with('count', $s ? $s->count : 0)`, then in your file `example.blade.php`, you can access `$count` and see the value, number of rows or 0

Comment: Thank you again Tim! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Since this query returns an aggregate value (count) you won't be able to get any user information from it. However, you could remove the `->select(DB::raw('count(user_hobbies.user_id) as count'))` part which would end up returning a `Collection` with all the information from the joined tables. To get the count from that, just use the `Collection`'s `->count()` method.

```php
$groups = Group::leftJoin('user_hobbies', 'user_hobbies.hobby_id', '=', 'groups.hobby_id')
               ->where('groups.hobby_id', $this->hobby_id)
               ->get();
```

```xml
@foreach ($groups as $group)
    <p>{{ $group->hobby_id; }}</p>
    <p>{{ $group->user_id; }}</p>
@endforeach
<p>Count: {{ $groups->count() }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not looking to count anything though, I was wondering if there was a door in that function to get access to the user info and not just a count. I tried this code but on my page is appearing a really long number machine code looking number, is it still counting something??

Comment: This code just echoes ids. I didn't know any other columns your tables have. Try replacing `hobby_id` and `user_id` in the last part by some of your table columns.